# Is my Saints Row IV game bugged?

Tags: technical-issues, saints-row-iv

I'm doing the "Matt's Back" mission, and when I get to the point where I'm on a ship shooting other ships with a turret, I kill one ship and then my ships stops moving and nothing happens. I'm on the PS3 version. Also, I'm using the all upgrades, infinite sprint, clear notoriety, give cash, heaven bound, vehicle no damage, vehicle smash cheats.

Comment: Does *everything* on the screen freeze?

Comment: No, I can aim, shoot, go into the HUB, pause, and use the PS button, my ship just stops moving. I tried pressing every button on my controller.

Comment: I've not heard of this particular bug, although it wouldn't surprise me...  you might try playing this mission without the cheats and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Have cheats been known to bug people's games?

Comment: @Julum-Ei Cheats are bits of code that can interfere with other parts of the game. I.E. Unlimited health cheat when you're supposed to die. I would agree with agent86 here, attempt it without cheats as it may very well interfere with the scripted mission progress. (Especially if the ship is supposed to explode or a variable is missing that needs to be monitored [Can happen during Class Instantiation with a Cheat labeled TRUE where the Health variable is skipped] -- AKA for brackets [missing health counter piece.])

Comment: Redoing the mission without cheats worked. (Although they still seemed to be in effect, anyway.)

Comment: @Julum-Ei You should post that as an answer to make your solution more clear to others who might stumble across this later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to turn off all cheats before doing story missions.